# Retain the html input value after post back?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Asp.Net MVC 4 has the following code in the Index View.

```
<form action="/Deal" method="GET">
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        <input type="text" name="search"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</form>
```

And the following code in the DealController. However, the html search input is emtpy after post back. What's the best way to display the typed search string in the input box so users can continue modify it?

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    var deals = Deals.Include(d => d.Address);
    if (search != null)
        deals =
            deals.Where(d => d.Address.ApartmentNum.Contains(search) 
                             || d.Address.StreetAddress.Contains(search)
                             || d.Address.City.Contains(search) 
                             || d.Address.State == search 
                             || d.Address.Zip == search);
    return View(deals.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found just need to use the old way

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="@Request.QueryString["search"]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the best, but one of the easier ways.

```
 <form action="/Deal" method="GET">
     <p>
         @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
         <input type="text" name="search" value= "@((string)ViewBag.Search)" />
         <input type="submit" value="Search" />
     </p> 
</form>

public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    var deals = Deals.Include(d => d.Address);
    if (search != null)
        deals =
            deals.Where(d => d.Address.ApartmentNum.Contains(search) 
                             || d.Address.StreetAddress.Contains(search)
                             || d.Address.City.Contains(search) 
                             || d.Address.State == search 
                             || d.Address.Zip == search);
    ViewBag.Search = search;
    return View(deals.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Found just need to use the old way `<input type="text" name="search" value="@Request.QueryString["search"]"/>
`